# JavaScript equivalent of PHP's in_array()

Tags: php, javascript, phpjs

Is there a way in JavaScript to compare values from one array and see if it is in another array?

Similar to PHP's [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array) function?

Comment: FIRST SEE THIS ANSWER: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-in-array#answer-40717204 tldr; `var a = [1, 2, 3]; a.includes(2); // true`

Answer (score 280, accepted):

No, it doesn't have one. For this reason most popular libraries come with one in their utility packages. Check out jQuery's *[inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)* and Prototype's *[Array.indexOf](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Array/prototype/indexOf/)* for examples.

jQuery's implementation of it is as simple as you might expect:

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you are dealing with a sane amount of array elements the above will do the trick nicely.

**EDIT**: Whoops. I didn't even notice you wanted to see if an array was inside another. According to the PHP documentation this is the expected behavior of PHP's [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array):

```
$a = array(array('p', 'h'), array('p', 'r'), 'o');

if (in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a)) {
    echo "'ph' was found\n";
}

if (in_array(array('f', 'i'), $a)) {
    echo "'fi' was found\n";
}

if (in_array('o', $a)) {
    echo "'o' was found\n";
}

// Output:
//  'ph' was found
//  'o' was found
```

The code posted by Chris and Alex does not follow this behavior. Alex's is the official version of Prototype's indexOf, and Chris's is more like PHP's [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/array_intersect). This does what you want:

```
function arrayCompare(a1, a2) {
    if (a1.length != a2.length) return false;
    var length = a2.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (a1[i] !== a2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(typeof haystack[i] == 'object') {
            if(arrayCompare(haystack[i], needle)) return true;
        } else {
            if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this my test of the above on it:

```
var a = [['p','h'],['p','r'],'o'];
if(inArray(['p','h'], a)) {
    alert('ph was found');
}
if(inArray(['f','i'], a)) {
    alert('fi was found');
}
if(inArray('o', a)) {
    alert('o was found');
}  
// Results:
//   alerts 'ph' was found
//   alerts 'o' was found
```

Note that I intentionally did not extend the Array prototype as it is generally a bad idea to do so.

Comment: `jQuery.inArray()` does **not** return boolean.  It returns the index of the found element or -1 if not found

Comment: Due to the high rating - you should mark your answer as outdated

Comment: this is documentation of `indexOf` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Comment: yes, this answer is outdated, the correct answers are below

Answer (score 173):

There is now [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain
>   element, returning true or false as appropriate.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.includes(2); // true 
a.includes(4); // false
```

> Syntax

```
arr.includes(searchElement)
arr.includes(searchElement, fromIndex)
```

Comment: Reminder: This doesn't work in IE11 (or any other version of Internet Explorer). For the rare cases were that still needs to be supported.

Comment: In the MDN function page there is a polyfill, but only in portuguese version: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 71):

[`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) was introduced in JavaScript 1.6, but it is not supported in older browsers. Thankfully the chaps over at Mozilla have done [all the hard work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) for you, and provided you with this for compatibility:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

There are even some handy usage snippets for your scripting pleasure.

Comment: This is a nicer/safer/better implementation of the links/code posted here already; the specs don't call for checking for arrays inside the haystack, and that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Incidentally, what's the purpose of `this.length >>> 0`? Is that a conversion to a Number type?

Comment: `Array.indexOf` is now standardised by ECMAScript Fifth Edition so should be considered the proper ‘native’ way of doing it. You will still need to sniff and provide this backup for older browser for a long time, though. @harto: yes, it converts `this.length` to a Number that can be represented as a 32-bit unsigned integer. A native `Array` can only have a length that already complies with this, but the spec states that you can call `Array.prototype` methods on native-JS objects that are not `Array`. This and the other pedantic argument checking stuff is to guarantee absolute spec-compliance.

Comment: There's a different polyfill version available directly from Mozilla - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @harto I answer 8 years after your comment but maybe someone else could have the same question => see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it

Answer (score 45):

PHP way:

```php
if (in_array('a', ['a', 'b', 'c'])) {
   // do something if true
}
```

My solution in JS:

```js
if (['a', 'b', 'c'].includes('a')) {
   // do something if true
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can simply use the "includes" function as explained in [this lesson on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)

it looks like

```js
let myArray = ['Kevin', 'Bob', 'Stuart'];
if( myArray.includes('Kevin'))
console.log('Kevin is here');
```

Answer (score 14):

If the indexes are not in sequence, or if the indexes are not consecutive, the code in the other solutions listed here will break.  A solution that would work somewhat better might be:

```
function in_array(needle, haystack) {
    for(var i in haystack) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And, as a bonus, here's the equivalent to PHP's array_search (for finding the key of the element in the array:

```
function array_search(needle, haystack) {
    for(var i in haystack) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return i;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice drop in replacement. Really made porting from php to node easy. thanks

Answer (score 10):

There is a project called [Locutus](http://locutus.io), it implements PHP functions in Javascript and [in_array()](http://locutus.io/php/array/in_array) is included, you can use it exactly as you use in PHP.

Examples of use:

```
in_array('van', myArray);

in_array(1, otherArray, true); // Forcing strict type
```

Comment: There is also  a inArray function in JQuery's APIs. Check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: @ahPo, Nice! But the Locutus implementation has the advantage to be pure javascript with no dependencies. So, choose the best one for your needs

Comment: or you can just import the required [function](http://locutus.io/php/array/in_array/) from Locutus.

Answer (score 8):

jQuery solution is available, check the ducumentation here:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

```
$.inArray( 10, [ 8, 9, 10, 11 ] );
```

Comment: don't forget to check like this: if($.inArray( 10, [ 8, 9, 10, 11 ] ) > -1) because I did like this: if($.inArray( 10, [ 8, 9, 10, 11 ] )) and it always returns true

Comment: PS: This is type sensitive so if checking for numbers make sure your datatypes match!
ie: $.inArray( '10', [ 8, 9, 10, 11 ] ); would return -1

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

var isSixInArray = a.filter(function(item){return item==6}).length ? true : false;

var isSixInArray = a.indexOf(6)>=0;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an equivalent function:

```
includes()
```

Look here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: be carefull with that function it has currently no full browser support

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to check if a single value is in an array, then Paolo's code will do the job. If you want to check which values are common to both arrays, then you'll want something like this (using Paolo's inArray function):

```
function arrayIntersect(a, b) {
    var intersection = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(inArray(b, a[i]))
            intersection.push(a[i]);
    }

    return intersection;
}
```

This wil return an array of values that are in both `a` and `b`. (Mathematically, this is an [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of the two arrays.)

**EDIT:** See [Paolo's Edited Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-inarray/784015#784015) for the solution to your problem. :)

Comment: Although this is nice, it is not really what the OP asked for; it doesn't replicate the functionality of PHP's in_array.

Answer (score 3):

If you need all the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) available parameters, use this:

```
function in_array(needle, haystack, argStrict) {
    var key = '', strict = !!argStrict;
    if (strict) {
        for (key in haystack) {
            if (haystack[key] === needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (key in haystack) {
            if (haystack[key] == needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function in_array(needle, haystack){

    return haystack.indexOf(needle) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: This only returns whether it's the first element in the array; if `indexOf(needle) > 0` it will return false

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to you project and use the object-style inArray methods

```
if (!Array.prototype.inArray) {
    Array.prototype.inArray = function(element) {
        return this.indexOf(element) > -1;
    };
} 
//How it work
var array = ["one", "two", "three"];
//Return true
array.inArray("one");
```

Answer (score 2):

With [Dojo Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit), you would use `dojo.indexOf()`. See *[dojo.indexOf](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/indexOf.html)* for the documentation, and *[Arrays Made Easy](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/arrays/)* by Bryan Forbes for some examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
haystack.find(value => value == needle)
```

where haystack is an array and needle is an element in array. If element not found will be returned undefined else the same element.

Answer (score 1):

```
function in_array(what, where) {
    var a=false;
    for (var i=0; i<where.length; i++) {
        if(what == where[i]) {
            a=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a great jQuery solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204283/how-to-check-whether-multiple-values-exist-within-an-javascript-array/9204307#9204307) on SO.

```
var success = $.grep(array_a, function(v,i) {
    return $.inArray(v, array_b) !== -1;
}).length === array_a.length;
```

I wish someone would post an example of how to do this in underscore.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent of `in_array` with `underscore` is [_.indexOf](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf)

Examples:

`_.indexOf([3, 5, 8], 8);   // returns 2, the index of 8
_.indexOf([3, 5, 8], 10);   // returns -1, not found`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use it in a class, and if you prefer it to be functional (and work in all browsers):

```
inArray: function(needle, haystack)
{
    var result = false;

    for (var i in haystack) {
        if (haystack[i] === needle) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope it helps someone :-)

Answer (score -2):

```
var value = 'a';
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
if(array.indexOf(value)){
    // exists in array
} else {
   // Not exists in array
}
```

Comment: index of returns a number (not a boolean). if the value isn't present in the array -1 is returned