# What does the bitwise operator >>> do in Mozilla's map() implementation?

Tags: javascript, mozilla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Mozilla's Array.prototype.map(), described in the [Javascript 1.5 documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/map), is implemented with the following:

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
  Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        res[i] = fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

The line I'm struggling to understand is:

```
var len = this.length >>> 0;
```

Mozilla's Js 1.5 [bit-wise operator reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), explains that >>> is the bitwise operator *Zero-fill right shift*.

> **Zero-fill right shift**
>
> Shifts *a* in binary representation *b* (<
>   32) bits to the right, discarding bits
>   shifted off, and shifting in zeros
>   from the left.

Does this provide some kind of safety that returning *array.length* does not, or is this some kind of type coercion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it) (that question asks about the exact same line of code. It also leads to more exact duplicates.)

Comment: array.length is already an integer, and >>> always results in an integer.  (null>>>0)===0, ("blargh">>>0)===0, (undefined>>>0)===0...  I do not see why the line of code is necessary either.

Comment: Maybe it's if either the length property is redefined on Array or more likely, so that the function can be called on other array like objects

Comment: In particular the ECMAScript standard requires that `Array.prototype.map` be applicable to other array-like objects. On array-likes that are not Array instances, it is possible to set the `length` property to a non-integer. The ECMAScript standard, being a standard, defines what exactly should happen when you do something crazy like this, and Mozilla are simply replicating what the spec says should happen in this unlikely corner case.