# What is this JavaScript operator mean? >>>

Tags: javascript, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it)

I was browsing through some documentation on MDN for the indexOf workaround ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/IndexOf)) and I came across this line of code:

```
var len = t.length >>> 0;
```

Was just curious what that did, as I've never seen it.

**Answer is in the first comment.**

Comment: @bobince 's answer in the linked duplicate is superb.

Comment: @Michael yea I'm embarrassed now :-)

Comment: sorry about that. thx for the reference.

Comment: `array.length = 'LEMONS';`. Aha, got it `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsigned right shift. See [Unsigned Right Shift Operator (>>>) (JavaScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342xfs5s%28v=VS.94%29.aspx)
.