# what does << do in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Absolute Beginner's Guide to Bit Shifting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting)
>   [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it)

I came across `<<` while reading some code.

```
1<<1 //2
2<<1 //4
3<<1 //6
3<<2 //12
```

What is this called?

What does this do?

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141873/15055):

---

### Left shift (<<)

Integers are stored, in memory, as a series of bits.  For example, the number 6 stored as a 32-bit `int` would be:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110
```

Shifting this bit pattern to the left one position (`6 << 1`) would result in the number 12:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001100
```

As you can see, the digits have shifted to the left by one position, and the last digit on the right is filled with a zero.  You might also note that shifting left is equivalent to multiplication by powers of 2.  So `6 << 1` is equivalent to `6 * 2`, and `6 << 3` is equivalent to `6 * 8`.  A good optimizing compiler will substitute shifts for multiplications when possible.

#### Non-circular shifting

Please note that these are *not* circular shifts.  Shifting this value to the left by one position (`3,758,096,384 << 1`):

```
11100000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

results in 3,221,225,472:

```
11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

The digit that gets shifted "off the end" is lost.  It does not wrap around.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [bitwise left shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirect=no).

`a << b` will shift `b` bits to the left of the binary representation of `a`.