# Bit shifting/type casting in javascript with unsigned 32 bit integers?

Tags: c#, javascript, types

I'm trying to convert some complex C# bitshifting code into javascript (node), but I'm having issues with this kind of conversion as an example:

```
var d = false;
var k = 61;
var dd = 103;

uint r = 2924539136;
r |= unchecked((byte)(d ? (k + dd) : (k - dd)));

Console.WriteLine("result: " + r);  // 2924539350
```

Is there some way to replicate the (byte) casting in javascript to where it computes the value I'm looking for, I have this so far, but it just results in -42.

```
r |= (d ? (k + dd): (k - dd));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = false;
var k = 61;
var dd = 103;

r = 2924539136;

b = (d ? (k + dd) : (k - dd))
x = (r | (b & 0xFF)) >>> 0
```

returns

```
x = 2924539350
```

The trick is to use `&0xFF` to mask all but lower 8 bits in `b` and `>>>0` [to convert a signed 32-bit number to unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1822769/989121).