# what's the difference between bitwise shift with 2 arrows and 3 arrows?

Tags: java, javascript, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I've seen `>>` and `>>>` before. **What is the difference and when to use each?**

Comment: Using three arrows "zeros fills"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double Arrows ">>" and Triple Arrows ">>>" are defined on 32-bit integers, so performing these on a variable will "convert" them so-to-speak from non-numbers, to numbers. Additionally, javascript numbers are stored as double precision floats, so these operations will also cause you to lose any precision bits higher than 32 . ">>" maintains the sign bit (result is a signed integer), while ">>>" does not (result is an unsigned integer).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342xfs5s%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

For a much better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1822769/780399

Answer (score 16):

Others have provided the explanations.

- `>>>` shifts all the bits, even the sign bit (the MSB)
- `>>` keeps the sign bit in place and shifts all the others

This is best explained with some sample code:

```
int x=-64;

System.out.println("x >>> 3 = "  + (x >>> 3));
System.out.println("x >> 3 = "  + (x >> 3));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x >>> 3));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x >> 3));
```

Output is the following:

```
x >>> 3 = 536870904
x >> 3 = -8
11111111111111111111111111000
11111111111111111111111111111000
```