# (-3>>>0).toString(2) vs (-3>>0).toString(2)

Tags: javascript, binary, bitwise-operators

Can someone please explain in details why `(-3>>0).toString(2)` doesn't return two's complement of `3` in the binary form `11111111111111111111111111111101`, whereas `(-3>>>0).toString(2)` returns does?

Both use bit shift, but the former uses `Sign-propagating right shift` and latter uses `Zero-fill right shift`. I've found this explanation:

> -3 >>> 0 (right logical shift) coerces its arguments to unsigned integers, which is why you get the 32-bit two's complement
>   representation of -3.

But I don't know what to make of it. Please provide elaborate answer if possible.

Comment: This has nothing to do with twos-complement. It's just `-3>>>0 == 4294967293` vs `-3>>0 == -3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Comment: @Bergi, still not clear :(. can you please elaborate?

Comment: Umm, why do you care about this?

Comment: @torazaburo, what do you mean? :)

Comment: @Maximus: The `>>>` operator casts its operand to an unsigned 32 bit integer. `-3` corresponds to `4294967293` - it's just modulo 2^32.

Comment: @Bergi, so what you're saying is that Javascript stores `-3` internally in the binary form `11111111111111111111111111111101`, but then when I use `>>>` operator Javascript simply takes that form and treats it as an unsigned integer?

Comment: @Maximus: No, `-3` is stored as a double, as every number in JS. It's just converted to that unsigned integer [using the algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-touint32) when the `>>>` operator is used on it.

Comment: @Bergi, I see now, thanks a lot! It'd be great if you posted a small summary as an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

it seems that >> just lefts the same sign while bitwise operation is made over absolute value:

```
var absValue = Math.abs(value), 
    sign = value / absValue;
value = sign * (Math.abs(value) >> base);
```

So there is not difference for positive/negative values, they are operated equally but saves their sign.

While >>> operates on full value(including complement forms for negative values) just by *treating* value as unsigned but not actual converting it.