# Why is this unsigned unshift assignment operator used in the find polyfill?

Tags: javascript

What follows is the polyfill for `Array.prototype.find` on MDN.

What purpose does the unsigned right shift assignment operator (`>>>`) serve in this code? (I can only think conversion to 32-bit integer?!)

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
    value: function(predicate) {
     'use strict';
     if (this == null) {
       throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
     }
     if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
       throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
     }
     var list = Object(this);
     var length = list.length >>> 0;
     var thisArg = arguments[1];
     var value;

     for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       value = list[i];
       if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
         return value;
       }
     }
     return undefined;
    }
  });
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it

Comment: Chained duplicates :)