# In JavaScript, can bit shifting be used to isolate 1 or more bits in a byte?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript code where the 8 bits of a byte represent 8 Boolean "decisions" (aka: flags), there is a need to isolate each given bit for conversion to a Boolean variable. Consider my solution using String parsing:

```
var bitParser = function (_nTestByte, _nBitOrdinal) {
  var bits = ("00000000" + _nTestByte.toString(2)).slice(-8); // convert to binary and zero-pad
  return bits[_nBitOrdinal] === "1";
};

console.log(bitParser(0b10100101, 2)); // ECMAScript 6+ prefix, returns true
```

It works, and shows the desired result. However I have a hypothesis stating that  a bit shifting technique would be a faster option than String manipulation. I tend to believe that but desire to prove it.

The problem is, I have yet to produce such a function that works correctly, let alone something I can test. I have created the following logic plan that I believe is accurate:

```
/*
  LOGIC PLAN
  ----------
  0) Remember: all bitwise operators return 32 bits even though we are using 8
  1) Left shift until the desired bit is the left-most (highest) position;
  2) Right shift (zero filling) 31 bits to eliminate all right bits
*/
```

The implementation of the login plan follows. Because of the 32 bit nature of bitwise operators, its my belief that the entire left 3 bytes (24 bits) must be shifted off first before we even reach the byte being worked on. Then, assuming a scenario where the 3rd bit from the left (String ordinal 2) is the desired bit, I am shifting off 2 more bits (ordinals 0 & 1), for a total of 26 bits of left shifting.

This should produce a binary number with the desired bit all the way left followed by 31 undesired zero bytes. Right shifting those 31 bits away produces a binary with 31 (now) leading zero bits which evaluates to whatever the value of the desired bit is. But of course, I would not be writing this question if THAT were true, now would I?    :-)

```
// hardcoded, assuming the second "1" (ordinal 2) is the bit to be examined
console.log((0b10100101 << 26) >> 31); // instead of 1, returns -1
```

I feel like I am really close, but missing something or pushing JavaScript too hard (lol).

Comment: What is the actual goal? This is a **lot** more work than necessary if you just want to do bit testing for converting bitflags to booleans.

Comment: The actual goal is to produce a function which does the job specified in the first paragraph of the question. Testing performance of the two approaches would then follow. I apologize if that was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In JavaScript code where the 8 bits of a byte represent 8 Boolean "decisions" (aka: flags), there is a need to isolate each given bit for conversion to a Boolean variable...

If that's the actual goal, bitshifting is neither necessary nor useful: Just use a bitwise `&` with the desired bit, which will give you either `0` or a number with that bit set. `0` is falsy, the number with a bit set is truthy. You can either use that as-is, or force it to boolean via `!!flag` or `Boolean(flag)`:

Here's your `bitParser` function using bitmasking:

```js
var bitParser = function (_nTestByte, _nBitOrdinal) {
  return !!(_nTestByte & Math.pow(2, _nBitOrdinal));
};
console.log(bitParser(0b10100101, 2)); // true
console.log(bitParser(0b10100101, 1)); // false
```

Rather than doing the `Math.pow` every time, of course, we'd probably be better off with a lookup table:

```js
var bits = [
  0b00000001,
  0b00000010,
  0b00000100,
  0b00001000,
  0b00010000,
  0b00100000,
  0b01000000,
  0b10000000
];
var bitParser = function (_nTestByte, _nBitOrdinal) {
  return !!(_nTestByte & bits[_nBitOrdinal]);
};
console.log(bitParser(0b10100101, 2)); // true
console.log(bitParser(0b10100101, 1)); // false
```

Comment: I was clearly overthinking this. Concise answer with tests. Thank you.

Comment: @GeekStocks: No worries. I actually was *literally* just now replacing that old snippet with your `bitParser` converted to use this instead, because it's not obvious (though clearly it was to you) how `_nBitOrdinal` becomes the right bit value to mask with.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you do mean to use a bitwise and instead of logical?

Comment: @WillieScholtz: Thank you!! Fixed. When updating the answer with `bitParser` instead of my original example, I grabbed the OP's code and didn't notice! (Note to self: Always include the negative test, too.)

Answer (score 1):

From your question I took

`console.log((0b10100101 << 26) >> 31); //instead of 1, returns -1`.

And to answer your question why it returned -1 instead of 1

You need to do  unsigned right shift `>>>` instead of signed one `>>`

```js
console.log((0b10100101 << 26 ) >>>31);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, and what you're doing is almost correct.

Integers are represented as a 32bit binary number, with the leftmost bit representing the sign (it's `1` if the number is negative and `0` if the number is positive). Lets look at some of the numbers' representations:

```
//last 31 digits keeps increasing as the number decreases
// ...
-2 => 0b11111111111111111111111111111110
-1 => 0b11111111111111111111111111111111
 0 => 0b00000000000000000000000000000000
 1 => 0b00000000000000000000000000000001
 2 => 0b00000000000000000000000000000010
// ...
// last 31 digits keep increasing as the number increases
```

Now, what you're having `(0b10100101 << 26)` should give you `10010100000000000000000000000000`, which you'd expect to be a big negative number (because the left-most bit is `1`). Then right afterwards, you have `>> 31` which you're expecting to strip off all 31 bits and leave you with the left-most bit.

That should work, but it's not what's happening. And why is that? It's because the people who came up with ECMAScript thought it would make more sense if  `4 >> 1` returns `2` and `-4 >> 1` returns `-2`.

```
4 >> 1 // returns 2 which is 0b00000000000000000000000000000010
0b0000000000000000000000000000000100 >> 1 // returns 2, same

-4 >> 1 // returns -2, which is 0b11111111111111111111111111111110
```

But -4 is `0b11111111111111111111111111111100`, and for your purposes right shifting it by 1 should yield `0b01111111111111111111111111111110` (big positive number, since left-post bit is 0), and that's not `-2`!

To overcome that, you can use the other right shift operator which doesn't care about about the sign: `>>>`. `-4 >>> 1` is `2147483646` which is what we want.

So `console.log((0b10100101 << 26) >>> 31);` gives you `1`, which is what you want. You can also keep using `>>` and regarding any negative outcome to be a result of `1` being the chosen bit.

Comment: I will have to study this further because I don't yet see why the 0b10100101 << 26 yields a negative number in the first place. I think your answer may actually answer the question as stated in the title, even though there was most definitely an easier way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Ahhh! I think I see it! I am CREATING a negative number with << ANYTIME the desired bit happens to be a 1, aren't I? So now I am looking up >>> to better understand HOW it ignores the sign. Apparently it MUST keep the bit but just change its use of it, yes? Instead of using it to indicate a negative, it uses it as part of the value?

Comment: I think this SO answer on another question answers my remaining question on your answer better than Mozilla's docs do : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1822369/1884386

Comment: Yes, you are creating the negative number as you stated =). And yes, you're exactly right. `>>>` is different because it deals with the left-most bit of an integer as a part of the binary number it operates on; thus starts putting 0s from the beginning as it should. `>>` would start putting 0s starting from after the sign bit.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I can't help but think this question has 2 right answers.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to achieve your actual need is to use simple conditions rather than trying to isolate bits.

```js
    var bitParser = function (_nTestByte, _nBitOrdinal) {
      return (_nTestByte & _nBitOrdinal);
    };
    
    console.log(bitParser(6, 2) ? true : false); // true
    console.log(bitParser(6, 1) ? true : false); // false
```

I adapted the `console.log()` expression in a way that may seem complicated.
It's only to really show the *logical* result at this step, while I didn't choose to use `!!` inside of the function, so returning a truly/falsy value rather than `true`|`false`.

Actually this way keeps all the most simple possible, because the expected use else where in the code is `if (bitParser(...))`, which automatically casts the result to boolean.

BTW, this works whatever is the `_nTestByte` size (may be more than 1 byte).

Comment: how would this get the flag if `_nBitOrdinal` is 7, i.e the 7th position; since 7  is represented as `00000111`. if `_nTestByte` is `0b01000000` the result would be 0?

Comment: @WillieScholtz The OP states " the 8 bits of a byte represent 8 Boolean "decisions" (aka: flags)". So from my point of view his need was to test `_nBitOrdinal` values like `1`, `2`, `4` and so on. In other words, each "flag" sould be a power of 2. Then my proposed solution works fine.

Comment: @WillieScholtz BTW after examining other answers (and reading OP more carefully) I realize that the need seems to be different... andI actually don't understand what it is: why `_nTestByte` has to be expressed binary? And why its (apparent) value doesn't match what I'd find the correct result when tested? Actually I'm totally puzzled!

Comment: @WillieScholtz And finally I just modified my answer to exactly reflect how I understand the OP.