# What use-cases exist for using >>>= operator with 0? (Unsigned Right Bit Shift)

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

I recently came across a strange piece of code that uses the `>>>=` operator (I'll show it later in the question).

---

The `>>>` is the [unsigned right bit shift](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsoprurshift.htm) operator, as mentioned in [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it)

The [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) describes the operator as...

> `a >>> b` shifts `a` in binary representation `b` (< 32) bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off, and shifting in zeroes from the left.

Given this knowledge, I have assumed that `>>>=` is the **in-place unsigned right bit shift** operator.

### The strange piece of code

Remember that piece of code I mentioned at the start? Here it is...

```
(number) => {
    number >>>= 0;
    // Do stuff with number...
}
```

I'm very curious as to **why someone would perform an in-place bit shift with `0`**.

What are the use-cases?

### The attempt to find use-cases

In an attempt to answer my question, I wrote a quick script that would iterate through all unsigned 32-bit integers and compare the integer to its (unsigned right shifted by 0) counterpart.

```
"use strict";

const assertEqual = (a, b, message) => {
    if (a !== b) {
        throw message
    }
}

const START = 0
const END = Math.pow(2, 32) - 1
for (let n = START; n < END; n++) {
    let nShifted = n
    nShifted >>>= 0
    const message = n + " !== (" + n + " >>>= 0) (which is " + nShifted + ")"
    assertEqual(n, nShifted, message)
}
console.log("done.")
```

As expected, the program finished with no exceptions, since bit-shifting by 0 will have no effect.

This, however, would throw an exception if any of the values were negative.

### More experimenting

- It appears that performing the shift truncates the result into a 32-bit integer, which isn't surprising.
- It also appears that when shifting negative integers, the result is the two's complement, which makes sense because it's making the value unsigned.

For example...

```
x = -1
console.log(x.toString(2))  // '-1'
x >>>= 0
console.log(x.toString(2))  // '11111111111111111111111111111111'
                            // (Two's complement of -1)
```

- As mentioned in the comments, using the operator on floating-point numbers will truncate the decimal section and result in an integer.

For example...

```
x = 2.6
x >>>= 0
console.log(x)  // '2'
```

### Summary

In-place right shifting by 0 an integer will truncate it to 32 bits and make it unsigned.

Are there any other use cases for this?

Comment: Try with `x = 2.6` and see what you get.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It truncates the floating-point part. Cool, I've mentioned it in my question now.