# >>> (Zero-fill right shift) when second oprand is zero

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I understand what is Zero-fill right shift and results it yields make perfect sense when second operand is non-zero:

```
-7 >>> 1
2147483644
```

Compare with

```
-7 >> 1
-4
```

But when second operand is zero:

```
-7 >> 0
-7 // Looks right!
-7 >>> 0
4294967289 // What? Why?
```

If I'm shifting zero bits, doesn't it mean I'm not shifting at all? If that's the case, shouldn't it give me back the original number? I would expect `-7 >>> 0 === -7`

And also

```
-7 >>> 32
4294967289
```

Again, by definition, I would expect `-7 >>> n === 0 where n >= 32` because all digits become zeros!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it

Comment: @DAle that helps. And the spec gives the exact mechanism. See below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the internal workings of it in [specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0).

`x >>> 0` will do `ToUint32(x)`

And

> 7.1.6 ToUint32 ( argument )
>
> The abstract operation ToUint32 converts argument to one of 232
>   integer values in the range 0 through 232−1, inclusive. This abstract
>   operation functions as follows: Let number be ToNumber(argument).
>   ReturnIfAbrupt(number). If number is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return
>   +0. Let int be the mathematical value that is the same sign as number and whose magnitude is floor(abs(number)). Let int32bit be int modulo
>   232. Return int32bit.

Note **Let int32bit be int modulo**, and

> The notation “x modulo y” (y must be finite and nonzero) computes a
>   value k of the same sign as y (or zero) such that abs(k) < abs(y) and
>   x−k = q × y for some integer q.

So by above convention, `-7 mod 2^32 === 2^32 - 7 === 4294967289`