# What does `>>>` mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, bitwise-operators

What is the meaning of the expression `>>>` in JavaScript? It is like type conversion, or what, and when it recommended to use?

I ran into that symbol (`>>>`) when I read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) and am a little confused.

Sorry, if my question is stupid, but I can not find any answers by Google search or other ways.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This question has already been asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it
Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

`>>>` is a **bitwise operator**.

> **>>>** **(Zero-fill right shift)** This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the
>   right are discarded. Zero bits are shifted in from the left. The sign
>   bit becomes 0, so the result is always non-negative.
>
> For non-negative numbers, zero-fill right shift and sign-propagating
>   right shift yield the same result. For example, 9 >>> 2 yields 2, the
>   same as 9 >> 2

*From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators*