# Why does `number |= 0` convert to 32bit integer?

Tags: javascript

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616484/6096764) I found the following piece of code:

```
hash = hash | 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
```

Could anyone explain why this code converts `hash` to 32 bit integer?

Comment: Notice that [`>>> 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1822350/1048572) is more common: it ensures that the result is positive by converting to an *unsigned* 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that bitwise operators implicitly convert their arguments to 32-bit ints before applying the operator. Other than that, `| 0` performs a bitwise OR with `0`, which is essentially a no-op.

In the ES6 spec, the `|` operator is [defined as a binary operator in 12.11](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-binary-bitwise-operators), and then the [runtime semantics are defined in 12.11.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-binary-bitwise-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

In particular, steps 7 and 9 cast the arguments to 32-bit ints, and step 11 returns the result as a 32-bit int:

> The production *A* : *A @ B*, where @ is one of the bitwise operators in
>   the productions above, is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *A*.
> 2. Let *lval* be [GetValue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getvalue)(*lref*).
> 3. [ReturnIfAbrupt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*lval*).
> 4. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *B*.
> 5. Let *rval* be [GetValue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getvalue)(*rref*).
> 6. [ReturnIfAbrupt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*rval*).
> 7. **Let *lnum* be [ToInt32](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toint32)(*lval*).**
> 8. [ReturnIfAbrupt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*lnum*).
> 9. **Let *rnum* be [ToInt32](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toint32)(*rval*).**
> 10. [ReturnIfAbrupt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*rnum*).
> 11. Return the result of applying the bitwise operator @ to *lnum* and *rnum*. **The result is a signed 32 bit integer.**
>
> [emphasis added]

Answer (score 3):

It is because `|` is an bitwise operator. SO

```
hash = hash | 0;
```

performs the bitwise `or` operation, i.e bitwise `or` of hash and zero.

You will observe similar behaviour for other bitwise operators too, for example :

```js
var x = 4;

console.log(4 >> 1); // right shift bitwise operator
```

Thanks to @Keith to mention that" Bitwize operation in JS, are only 32bit signed int's." in comment.

Comment: Thank you, I know that, suppose we have 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 and zero, in which all bits are `0`. If we do | we will get 5 bytes.

Comment: @Jim2018  Bitwize operation in JS, are only 32bit signed int's.

Comment: @Keith if this is true, then this is the the key point and should be added to the answer.

Comment: @Jim2018 Yes, indeed I think the answer would benefit from this.  I'll leave this for amrender to update his answer if he wants too.

Comment: @Keith Thanks for the additional info. And please feel free to update my answer, thanks