# Check if Variable in array javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Short code for checking if a variable also exists inside an array is needed.
Im thinking something like this:

```
   var category='cars';
   if (in_array(category, some_array)){
       do stuff!
   }
```

Is there any such function in js?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no native "in_array"-function in JavaScript (as in PHP), check out this solution:

http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array:432

Also a search would have lead you here:

[JavaScript equivalent of PHP's in_array()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-in-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (some_array.indexOf(category) >= 0) {
   // do stuff
}
```

(Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Not native in IE, but the link you posted does show an example implementation using `Array.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(some_array[category] !== undefined){
  // it's there
}
```