# find the variable key based on its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have the following javascript variable:

```
var myList =
    {
        itemA: 0,
        itemB: 1,
        itemC: 2,
        itemD: 3,
        itemE: 4
    };
```

I have the value of the variable, ie 0, 1, 2 etc and need to find the corresponding key to it ie if I have 2, the key would be itemC.

How can I do this with javascript?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-in-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/shaneburgess/7DzUM/

```
    var myList =
    {
        itemA: 0,
        itemB: 1,
        itemC: 2,
        itemD: 3,
        itemE: 4
    };

$.each(myList,function(index,value){
    if(value == 2){ alert(index); }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to iterate over every property until you find the one with that value.

```
for(var prop in myList) 
    if(myList[prop] == value)
       return prop;
return NOT_FOUND; // or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

if u write this like this:

```
 var myList =
    {
    "itemA": "0",
    "itemB": "1",
    "itemC": "2",
    "itemD": "3",
    "itemE": "4"
};
```

it will be a json object. then u can get itemC like this myList.itemC

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop through using the .each jQuery function if you want a pure jQuery solution. 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/
However, isbadawi's method would work well also.