# match a string using all the strings in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, compare

Hello, I'm trying to make a simple matching game in javascript.

If the the user inserts the text `president goes crazy` in any way that contains every strings in word_tmp, then the word_tmp becomes true, and if he misses one string then it becomes false.

```
word_tmp = ['president', 'goes', 'crazy'];

// string 1 contains the president, goes and crazy at one string
string1 = 'president goes very crazy'; // should output true

// string 2 doesn't contain president so its false.
string2 = 'other people goes crazy'; // should output false
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string array contains one string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623272/how-to-check-if-a-string-array-contains-one-string-in-javascript)

Comment: the string2 would be true if we use that right?

Comment: You supposed to split the string and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var word_tmp = ['president', 'goes', 'crazy'];
var string1 = 'president goes very crazy';

var isMatch = true;
for(var i = 0; i < word_tmp.length; i++){
    if (string1.indexOf(word_tmp[i]) == -1){
        isMatch = false;
        break;
    }
}

return isMatch //will be true in this case
```

Comment: simplest one maybe if others need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call:

```
word_tmp.reduce(function(res, pattern) {
  return res && string1.indexOf(pattern) > -1;
}, true);
```

The same code, wrapped in a function:

```
var match_all = function(str, arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(res, pattern) {
    return res && str.indexOf(pattern) > -1;
  }, true);
};

match_all(string1, word_tmp); // true
match_all(string2, word_tmp); // false
```

But this solution won't work for you if you want to match whole words. I mean, it will accept strings like `presidential elections goes crazy`, because `president` is a part of the word `presidential`. If you want to eliminate such strings as well, you should split your original string first:

```
var match_all = function(str, arr) {
  var parts = str.split(/\s/); // split on whitespaces
  return arr.reduce(function(res, pattern) {
    return res && parts.indexOf(pattern) > -1;
  }, true);
};

match_all('presidential elections goes crazy', word_tmp); // false
```

In my example I'm splitting original string on whitespaces `/\s/`. If you allow punctuation marks then it's better to split on non-word characters `/\W/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var word_tmp = ['president', 'goes', 'crazy'];
var str = "president goes very crazy"

var origninaldata = str.split(" ")
var isMatch = false;
for(var i=0;i<word_tmp.length;i++) {
   for(var j=0;j<origninaldata.length;j++) {
      if(word_tmp[i]==origninaldata[j])
        isMatch = true;
   }
}
```