# How to check if the id exists in the array of ids javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like:

```
item: {
    b: null
    c: "asd"
    i: 10
    q: 10
    s: Array [237,241]}
```

Also I have an array of ids:

```
var ids = [237, 238, 239, 240, 242, 243...]
```

I dont know how to check if above ids exist in s, and then
save those items to new array or object

```
        for (var key in items) {
            for (var i in items[key].s) {
        //...
            }
        }
```

Comment: use `indexOf` or `includes`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @nisarg ii dont see an object :/

Comment: Originally I was going to flag with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12623272/5894241), but that is already marked a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 if(items.s.some(el => ids.includes(el))) alert("wohoo");
```

Simply check if some of the items ids is included in the ids array. Or using a for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.s.length; i++){
 if( ids.includes( items.s[i] )){
  alert("wohoo");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.filter` and `Array.indexOf`. I assume that you are not using any code transpiler, si I recommend using `indexOf` instead of `includes` as it has better browser support.

```
var foundIds = item.s.filter(x => ids.indexOf(x) !== -1);
// foundIds now contains the list of IDs that were matched in both `ids` and `item.s`
```

```js
var item = {
    b: null,
    c: "asd",
    i: 10,
    q: 10,
    s: [237,241]
}
var ids = [237, 238, 239, 240, 242, 243];

var foundIds = item.s.filter(x => ids.indexOf(x) !== -1);
console.log(foundIds);
```

Comment: It's ironic for you to not use `.includes()` due to it not being well supported, but then use an arrow function. The main thing that you would be trying to gain by not using `.includes()` would be IE support. IE doesn't support arrow functions either.

Comment: @Makyen arrow functions are better supported than Array.includes. Array.includes is not supported in Edge, while arrow functions are.

Comment: Yes, arrow functions are better supported than `.inlcudes()`. However, [`Array.prototype.includes()` was supported in Edge as of version 14](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility). Thus, the primary thing one gets by not using `.includes()` is IE support, for which you must also not use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: What I meant, is that `arrow functions` are from ES2015 and `.includes()` are from ES2016. I don't know the exact browser support, but I guess on mobile the difference is pretty large. Also, you are right, using arrow functions while mentioning the browser support issue was a bit ironic.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var item = {
  b: null,
  c: "asd",
  i: 10,
  q: 10,
  s: [237,241]
}
var ids = [237, 238, 239, 240, 242, 243];
// way number 1
for(var i = 0; i < item.s.length; i++){
  if( ~ids.indexOf(item.s[i])){
    console.log(item.s[i]);
  }
}
//way number 2
var myArr = item.s.filter(x => ~ids.indexOf(x));
console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ids.filter(id => items.s.includes(id))
```

"Filter" the list of `ids` to those which `items.s` "includes".