# How to check if the JSON Object array contains the value defined in an array or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following JSON data.

```
categories = [
    {catValue:1, catName: 'Arts, crafts, and collectibles'},
    {catValue:2, catName: 'Baby'},
    {catValue:3, catName: 'Beauty and fragrances'},
    {catValue:4, catName: 'Books and magazines'},
    {catValue:5, catName: 'Business to business'},
    {catValue:6, catName: 'Clothing, accessories, and shoes'},
    {catValue:7, catName: 'Antiques'},
    {catValue:8, catName: 'Art and craft supplies'},
    {catValue:9, catName: 'Art dealers and galleries'},
    {catValue:10, catName: 'Camera and photographic supplies'},
    {catValue:11, catName: 'Digital art'},
    {catValue:12, catName: 'Memorabilia'}
];

var categoriesJson = JSON.stringify(categories);
```

And following array.

```
var mainCat = ['Arts, crafts, and collectibles', 'Baby' , 'Antiques']
```

While looping the JSON data I need to check if the Object value is listed in an array or not. If the yes do something else do another thing.

For example

```
$.each(categoriesJson , function (key, value) {
    if(value.catName is in array) {
        //do something here 
    } else {
        //do something here
    }
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `array.indexOf(value.catName) !== -1` // is in array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string array contains one string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623272/how-to-check-if-a-string-array-contains-one-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/5894241

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var categories = [
    {catValue:1, catName: 'Arts, crafts, and collectibles'},
    {catValue:2, catName: 'Baby'},
    {catValue:3, catName: 'Beauty and fragrances'},
    {catValue:4, catName: 'Books and magazines'},
    {catValue:5, catName: 'Business to business'},
    {catValue:6, catName: 'Clothing, accessories, and shoes'},
    {catValue:7, catName: 'Antiques'},
    {catValue:8, catName: 'Art and craft supplies'},
    {catValue:9, catName: 'Art dealers and galleries'},
    {catValue:10, catName: 'Camera and photographic supplies'},
    {catValue:11, catName: 'Digital art'},
    {catValue:12, catName: 'Memorabilia'}
];

var categoriesJson = JSON.stringify(categories);
var mainCat = ['Arts, crafts, and collectibles', 'Baby' , 'Antiques']

$.each(JSON.parse(categoriesJson) , function (key, value) {
  if(mainCat.indexOf(value.catName) > -1){
   console.log('Exists: ' +value.catName)
 }
 else{
   console.log('Does not exists: ' +value.catName)
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the initial data array to get the array of matching categories:

```
var matchedCategories = categories.filter(i => mainCat.indexOf(i.catName) >= 0);
```

Then you could do what you need by iterating this sub-array.

Answer (score 0):

I also use *@dhilt* approach but with includes

ex. If even one is included (return bool)

```
  categories.filter(i =>
    mainCat.includes(i.catName)
  ).length > 0
    ? true
    : false;
```