# Check array of objects contains value

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm running into an issue where I have a response that contains an array of objects, the array isn't always in the same order based on the response, but I need to verify that at least 1 of the objects in the array of objects contains a specific value (or key/value pair).

For example, the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      foo: 'Name 1',
      bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
    },
    {
      foo: 'Name 2',
      bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
    },
    {
      foo: 'Name 3',
      bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
    }
```

}

I would use something like `expect(responseBody.data).toContainEqual({foo: "Name 2"})`, but that doesn't work. Would something like `toHaveProperty` work better? (Still not sure I understand the difference between `toEqual`, `toBe` and `toContainEqual` etc., as they feel very similar.

I suppose I need to add something, the object itself I'm checking may contain random data (like dates/timestamps/etc.), so I won't know specifically all data of the object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the JSON Object array contains the value defined in an array or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247020/how-to-check-if-the-json-object-array-contains-the-value-defined-in-an-array-or)

Comment: @KiranShahi I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. This question is specifically asking about how to do this with the playwright testing library, not with general JS.

Comment: @DanielBlack  The logic required here which enumerates the data set and then filters & matches for one specific value is independent of playwright so any general JS solution is fine as an abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct approach is to create an array of strings for the `foo` key, then use the `.toContain()` matcher to see if `"Name 2"` is in the array.

```js
expect(responseBody.data.map(e => e.foo)).toContain("Name 2");
```

Using `.some()` is less optimal because it'll produce a vague error message like "expected false to be true" rather than showing the array of values and the missing target value.

You can also [write your own matcher](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#add-custom-matchers-using-expectextend) but this may be overkill for this use case, especially if you don't need a web-first assertion.

Comment: I guess I could also use the `some()` method and check if that returns true?

Comment: @msmith1114 You could, but then the error message is less clear: "false was not true" rather than "`['Jack', 'Doug', 'Beverly']` did not contain `'Name 2'`".

Answer (score 3):

```
const responseBody = {
  data: [
    {
      foo: 'Name 1',
      bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
    },
    {
      foo: 'Name 2',
      bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
    },
    {
      foo: 'Name 3',
      bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
    }
  ]
};

const desiredValue = 'Name 2';

const containsDesiredValue = responseBody.data.some(obj => obj.foo === desiredValue);

expect(containsDesiredValue).toBe(true);
```

The above code checks whether any object in the array contains a specific value of "foo" key, using `some` method.

Previous code that I wrote in JS:

```js
function checkIfObjectPresent(inputArray, matchObj) {
  const size = inputArray.length;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    let curr = inputArray[i];
    
    if(JSON.stringify(curr) === JSON.stringify(matchObj)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

let data = [
  {
    foo: 'Name 1',
    bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
  },
  {
    foo: 'Name 2',
    bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
  },
  {
    foo: 'Name 3',
    bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
  }
]
  
let compWith = {
      foo: 'Name 1',
      bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
};

let compWith2 = {
  fool: 'Tmp',
  bar: '2022-06-07T00:00:00',
};
    
console.log(checkIfObjectPresent(data, compWith)); // returns true
console.log(checkIfObjectPresent(data, compWith2)); // returns false
```

Comment: I believe the asker is looking for how to do this within the playwright testing framework, not how to do this generally in JS.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question.

Should I take down the answer?

Comment: I modified my question because I need to check a single property:value because I don't know the other values of the object specifically (Since they may be timestamps/etc... so I cannot predict them)