# JavaScript - Detect string from array in input and output the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I want to detect if a user types one of the strings of my list and then output in what string the user typed in the console.

HTML

```
<input id="input"></input>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function(){
  var input = document.getElementById('formula');
  var strings = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]

  formula.onkeypress = function (e) {
    if (input.value.includes(strings)) {
      console.log("Input contains a the string:" + string???)
    }           
  };                   
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string array contains one string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623272/how-to-check-if-a-string-array-contains-one-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching element by the wrong ID. The ID of the input is `input`, and not `formula`. Ignoring this typo, you need to check the inclusion in the array instead. Replace this:

```
if (input.value.includes(strings)) {
```

with this:

```
if (strings.includes(input.value)) {
```

Additionally, using `keypress` event doesn't serve the purpose as the updated value will be fetched after you press one more key. Use `oninput` instead.

**Edit 1**:

You can use `Array#some` to check if the input value contains any string from the array.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var strings = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]

  input.oninput = function(e) {
    if (strings.some(str => input.value.includes(str))) {
      console.log("Input contains a the string:" + input.value)
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<input id="input"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Right now I have to write exactly "string1" to execute, but how do I make so it executes when the input contains "string1" for example if I type "some words string1"?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `String.indexOf()` and `Array.filter()`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var strings = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"];
  /* replaced `formula` with `input` */
  document.getElementById('input').oninput = function(e) {
    var find = this.value;
    if (0 < find.length) {
      var matches = strings.filter(function(s) {
        return -1 !== s.indexOf(find);
      });
      console.log('find string', find, ', matches found', matches);
    }
  };
};
```

```html
<input id="input" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use like it:-    
formula.onkeypress = function (e) {
      if (strings.includes(input.value)) {
      console.log("Input contains a the string:" + input.value)
      }           
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

1. The `id` is incorrect for `input` element
2. You need to use `onkeyup` event to get the immediately typed character
3. You need to use `includes()` in array type variable.

```js
window.onload = function(){

var input = document.getElementById('formula');

var strings = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]

input.onkeyup = function (e) {
  if (strings.includes(input.value)) {
  console.log("Input contains a the string:" + input.value)
  }           
};         

}
```

```html
<input id="formula" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an autocomplete form : [Autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp)