# Javascript , is there a way to make the javascript disable all links except one

Tags: javascript, html, joomla2.5

I want to redirect all links on one site to another domain. Except few menu links and one image in the site.. All I could find was this code, and it just disables all links
any ideas

```
function disable() {
  links=document.getElementsByTagName('A');
  for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].href="javascript:return false";
  }
}
window.onload=disable;
```

i want to show tons of demo templates that people can download , but those templates have all sorts of links that i dont want people to surf to , so i want to put one image inside the template saying Look at more templates. and thats the only link i want enabled

Comment: Which link you don't want to disable?

Comment: well, just put an if statement there and skip the ones you don't want to touch?

Comment: Why? This sounds like some pretty malicious ponzi scheme type garbage

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: i want to show tons of demo templates that people can download , but those templates have all sorts of links that i dont want people to surf to , so i want to put one image inside the template saying Look at more templates. and thats the only link i want enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the script you have as an example just set a conditional. I used the `inArray()` function described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-in-array). The basic logic is to set an array called `good_links` that is a list of links you do not want neutralized. And then by using the `inArray()` function, the `disable()` function can now logically traverse all links but ignore the `good_links`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function disable(){
        var good_links = new Array();
        good_links[0] = "http://www.google.com/";
        good_links[1] = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
        good_links[2] = "http://www.bing.com/";
        links=document.getElementsByTagName('A');
        for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
            if (!inArray(links[i].href, good_links)) {
                links[i].href="javascript:return false";
            }
        }
    }

    function inArray(needle, haystack) {
        var length = haystack.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    window.onload=disable;

</script>
```

Okay, here is my whole HTML file which works. The only links that should work are: Google, Yahoo & Bing. Apple, Catmoji & StackOverflow are disabled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

    function disable(){
        var good_links = new Array();
        good_links[0] = "http://www.google.com/";
        good_links[1] = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
        good_links[2] = "http://www.bing.com/";
        links=document.getElementsByTagName('A');
        for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
            if (!inArray(links[i].href, good_links)) {
                links[i].href="javascript:return false";
            }
        }
    }

    function inArray(needle, haystack) {
        var length = haystack.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    window.onload=disable;

    //]]>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a><br />
    <a href="http://www.apple.com/">http://www.apple.com/</a><br />
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">http://www.yahoo.com/</a><br />
    <a href="http://www.catmoji.com/">http://www.catmoji.com/</a><br />
    <a href="http://www.bing.com/">http://www.bing.com/</a><br />
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">http://www.stackoverflow.com/</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a pretty good javascript, but its not working, all the links are disabled, can you take a look at the code again... p.s. im putting this in the head of the page

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

    function disable(){
        var good_links = new Array();
        good_links[0] = "http://www.baroninn.is/";
        good_links[1] = "http://baroninn.is/index.php/utlit";
        good_links[2] = "http://www.bing.com/";
        links=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
            if (!inArray(links.href, good_links)) {
                links[i].href="javascript:return false";
            }
        }
    }

Comment: function inArray(needle, haystack) {
        var length = haystack.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    window.onload=disable;

</script>

Comment: Thanks for the response , it worked with the editing option ,, you forgot the //]]> at the end of the code ,, Thanks for all your help.

Comment: wow , thanks .. maybe one more thing and i will not use more of your time , can i make it browse back ,, something like this <a href="javascript:history.back()">

Comment: Oki, no problem. Thanks for all your help man. Saved me alot of time since im not familiar with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find some attribute of the links you do not want disabled, and then check for that while looping. For instance, if the image and menu links have `#` as their `href` attribute:

```
function disableLinks () {
    var allLinks=document.getElementsByTagName('A');

    for(var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
        if (allLinks[i].href !== '#') {
            allLinks[i].href="javascript:return false";
        }
    }
}

window.onload = disableLinks;
```

It may be worth mentioning that disabling/redirecting a bunch of links without a good reason is a great way to piss off your users and make them never return to your site.

Comment: sorry for the newbie question but how do i add the # to my links

Comment: @user2014557 it might help if you showed us the HTML for the links that you do not want disabled.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Apache, and you can differentiate between links to redirect and those not to, you could adapt an Apache mod_rewrite rule...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `(.*)` would have to change, but it's a start.

Comment: I dont have access to the apache, im not the hoster.

Comment: thanks for the response , but i dont have access to the apache.

Comment: i have access to the .htaccess file, but as of now they are htaccess.txt and to change that i need to contact my hosting service and ask them to enable something i cant remember now, so im trying to find an alternate way to disable all links except a few of them. but thanks for the response