# Validate all form fields on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically what i'm doing is passing 8 form input values to a Javascript Ajax file, during this process i want to do an

```
if(in_array(all form values) == 'empty') {
```

Here is the current code i'm using

```
if($("#merchant").val()==='') {
        //prevent submit button to sending to the handler page
        event.preventDefault();
        //popup the alert
        $("#response").html("<br/><div class='alert alert-error'>Please enter a Merchant Name</div>");
        $("#response").slideDown('slow');
        slideout();
        $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
}
```

But using this code i have to copy and paste it about 8 times for each field, which i would rather do an array check if possible.

Is this possible with Javascript ? if so how ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-in-array) (also, possibly a dupe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the `:inputs` of the form like this, assuming your in a `submit` event and the form is `this`

```
$(':input', this).each(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```

You could also potentially attach your error message as a data-attribute and reference it like this

```
<input type="text" ... data-error-msg="Some Error Message"/>

$(this).data('error-msg');
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because i'm not calling the values via a form, i'm calling them via the `id` attribute of the field.

Comment: I'm aware... I'm saying you shouldn't be calling them by the `id` attribute...  Gather them up in a different way, and then loop over them with `.each()`

Answer (score 0):

This function works perfect

```
function in_array(item,arr) {
     for(p=0;p<arr.length;p++) if (item == arr[p]) return true;
     return false;
}
```

Use it like this

```
if(in_array("value", myarray))
{
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: How would i go about checking for empty fields which hold no values ? because that's only checking items with a length of more than one ?

Comment: You can allways check with
if($(element).val() == "")

Im not sure anymore if i understood your problem

Comment: That's what i'm doing already, but i want to do it all in 1 with a simple function, instead of calling the same `if($("#merchant").val()==='') {` about 8 times, i'd rather do a simple `if(in_array('',$array);` but i don't know how to it in javascript

Answer (score -1):

This will only select elements that are empty:

```
$(".my-class:empty").each(function() {
    // Do things
});
```

Comment: Read the docs for the `:empty` selector....  http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Comment: They currently already have a class defined which is used all over the current page, which would incur a few problems