# What is wrong with my for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm a newbie on Javascript and I'm trying to do some exercises. I have found other ways on here that are more efficient at solving this, but anyway, here's how I tried doing it:

```
var char = prompt("Give me a letter");
char = char.toLowerCase();

function isVowel(char){
  var vowels = new Array('a','e','i','o','u');

  for(i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++){
    if(vowels[i] == char){
      return "This letter is a vowel.";
    }else{
      return "This letter is not a vowel.";
    }
  }
}
alert(isVowel(char));
```

Now, I understand this isn't the best way to do this, but I'd like to understand what's wrong with my for loop, since "a" is the only letter it recognizes as being a vowel.
Can someone point me out the reason why it isn't running trough the whole array?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason it isn't running through the whole array is because you `return` a value. That stops the function after the first iteration.

Comment: it should be: for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++)

Comment: Ya remove the else condition from the loop and place the return at the end of is vowel (after you have checked each character in `vowels`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not return until you have a definite "yes" or "no" answer.

Try something like this instead:

```
var char = prompt("Give me a letter");
char = char.toLowerCase();

function isVowel(char){
  var vowels = new Array('a','e','i','o','u');

  for(i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++){
    if(vowels[i] == char){
      return "This letter is a vowel.";
    }
  }
  return "This letter is not a vowel.";
}
alert(isVowel(char));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var char = prompt("Give me a letter");
char = char.toLowerCase();

function isVowel(char){
  var vowels = new Array('a','e','i','o','u');
  var isv = false;

  for(i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++){
    if(vowels[i] == char){
      isv = true;
      }
    }
  if( isv == true)
     return "This letter is a vowel.";
  else
     return "This letter is not a vowel.";
  }
}
alert(isVowel(char));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't running through the whole array is because you return a value. That stops the function after the first iteration.

Here's a simpler solution to identify vowels without having to loop through an array:

```
function isVowel(char) {

    if (vowels.indexOf(char) >= 0) {
        return "The character \""+char+"\" is a vowel.";
    } else {
        return "The character \""+char+"\" is NOT a vowel.";
    }

}

var vowels = new Array('a','A','e','E','i','I','o','O','u','U');

alert(isVowel('e'));
alert(isVowel('f'));
```

The `indexOf` functionality is based on the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-in-array#answer-16732633).

Here's a [working example (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/F3tLE/1/).