# Reproduce in plain Javascript the PHP function in_array(needle, haystack)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, function

If I want to *skip a number of items* in a `for loop` in PHP, I might use PHP's native `in_array(needle,haystack);` function in the following manner:

**PHP**

```
$Fruit = array('Apple','Banana','Cucumber','Grapes','Pear','Tomato');
$Salad = array('Tomato','Cucumber');
$Herb = array('Banana');

$countFruit = count($Fruit);

for ($i = 0; $i < $countFruit; $i++) {
if (in_array($Fruit[$i],$Salad)) continue;
$fruitBowl[] = $Fruit[$i];
}
```

This will give me a `$fruitBowl` of:

```
array('Apple','Banana','Grapes','Pear');
```

*I realize I could use the much simpler*

```
$fruitBowl = array_diff($Fruit,$Salad);
```

*but bear with me - I'm making up this example as I go along.*

How do I reproduce this (or something similar) in Javascript?

Here's what I have come up with:

**Javascript**

```
var Fruit = ['Apple','Banana','Cucumber','Grapes','Pear','Tomato'];
var Salad = ['Tomato','Cucumber'];
var Herb = ['Banana'];
var fruitBowl = [];

var countFruit = Fruit.length;

for (var i = 0; i < countFruit; i++) {
if (Salad.indexOf(Fruit[i]) !== -1) {continue;}
fruitBowl.push(Fruit[i]);
}
```

**Having got this far, my question is *specifically* this:**

Is the Javascript

```
if (Salad.indexOf(Fruit[i]) !== -1) {continue;}
```

now (in 2015) the standard way to reproduce

```
if (in_array($Fruit[$i],$Salad)) continue;
```

in PHP?

Or is there a less obscure way of going about it?

***N.B.*** I understand that **jQuery** has `inArray` and **Prototype** has `Array.indexOf` but I'm just looking for a plain JavaScript solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript equivalent of PHP's in\_array()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-in-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)