# search an array with value from another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, search

I'm trying to search an array of HTML elements with search value from another array. Inside a function `getElement()` there is an array `order` which holds string value. This array determines the order of search. Also there is another array `elements` with all the html elements to be searched. The function block looks like

```
getElement(){
    const order = ['email-error', 'name-error', 'age-error'];
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-status]')
    
}
```

When there is a validation error, html elements will be attached with `data-status` property. In case of a validation error, the `getElement()` function is called. The value of the `data-status` will be `email-error` for email input, `name-error` for name input etc.

What I'm trying to achieve is; for eg: take a value from `order` array, say `email-error`. Search the `elements` array if it has an element with `data-status="email-error"`. If it exists, return the element and stops the search; else search with all values from `order` array.

Comment: Do you have to define the `elements` variable? Because you could call `querySelectorAll('[data-status="email-error"]')` and so on.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could implement a nested loop.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
    if( order[i] == elements[j] ) {
      return orders[i] 
    }
  }
}
```

This will loop through both arrays fully, matching each value from one array to each value from the other unless there's a match, in which case it would return the matching element and break the loop.

You could also use the built in JS `.forEach()` method, which automatically loops through arrays.

```js
order.forEach(orderEl => {
    elements.forEach(elementEl => {
        if (orderEl === elementEl) {
             return orderEl
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written some HTML to test the code.

This is is the way to do it, if you want to loop over all array values and check:

```js
function getElement() {
        const order = ['email-error', 'name-error', 'age-error'];
        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-status]')
        let foundElement = null

        elements.forEach((elem) => {
            if (order.includes(elem.getAttribute('data-status')) && !foundElement) {
                foundElement = elem
            }
        })
        return foundElement
    }
    console.log(getElement())
```

```html
<div data-status="email-error"></div>
<div data-status="name-error"></div>
<div data-status="test-class"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could do a function on your own like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/784015/13604954

Or use the built-in [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40717204/13604954